# gzip compression for jquery - what i missed?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, gzip

trying to enable gzip compression for javascripts (jquery libs) I have on my site.

I do have enabled deflate in Apache's httpd.config file, and I have added next lines in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/javascript
```

But, when I check with Google's page speed web performance tool, it gives me information that js is not compressed.

Can you tell me what I do wrong and how can I enable gzip compression for my web app?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is mod_deflate loaded at all?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript isn't `text/javascript`, it is `application/javascript`.

Comment: JavaScript isn’t application/x-javascript, it’s [application/javascript](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4329).

Comment: i tryed on two web sites (servers) - on one it works, but not works on the other. on both httpd.conf contains LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so ... can you help me where to check to enable on second?